# Magento2 - When I enable google recaptcha it returns an error when submitting the form

Tags: magento2, forms, recaptcha, google-recaptcha

In my site with Magento 2.4.2 I have enabled google recaptcha v2 invisible on the registration form and contact us.
The problem is that when I try to register or submit the form on the contact page I always get this error message:

```
Something went wrong with reCAPTCHA. Please contact the store owner.
```

I have done multiple tests and the error message always comes back.
How can I go about solving it?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever find a solution to this? I am seeing the same.